# Looking for an alternative for WITH SQL statement, having interdependent temporary tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am working on a huge DB with many tables. I have a kind of working version with the ";WITH" statement but it have side effects on the whole database (it sometimes stops or slows down the ETL job)so I am looking for an alternative.

I tried to rewrite the query but then I get the

> multi-part identifier x could not be bound

because the tables build upon each other.

The kind of working version is:

```sql
USE[database]
;WITH[table1] AS 
(
  SELECT [RegionList].[Cluster]
         ,[RegionList].[Region]
         ,[Customer]
         ,[Key1]
         ,[Key2]
         ,MAX(..[TimeK].) AS [Time]
  FROM [table3]
  JOIN [RegionList] ON [RegionList].[Region] = [DRegion].[Region]
  JOIN [DTime] ON [table3].[TimeK] = [DTime].[TimeK]
  JOIN [PKey]  ON [table3].[Key2] = [PKey].[Key2]

  GROUP BY [RegionList].[Cluster]
         ,[RegionList].[Region]
         ,[Customer]
         ,[Key1]
         ,[Key2]

)
,[table2] AS
(
 SELECT [table3].[Name]
        ,[DProduct].[Product]
        ,[PKey].[Key2]
        ,CASE
             WHEN [table1].[time] IS NULL THEN [DProduct].[Product]
             WHEN ...
             ELSE NULL
        END AS [NotActive]
 FROM [table1]
 JOIN [DProduct] ON [table1].[Key1] = [DProduct].[Key1]
 JOIN [PKey]  ON [table3].[Key2] = [PKey].[Key2]
 JOIN [Name] ON [table3].[Name] = [DName].[Name]

)
SELECT [table2].[NotActive]
       ,[table2].[Name]
       ,[tabel1].[Time]
       ,[table1].[Region]   
FROM [table2]
JOIN [table1] ON [table1].[Key2] = [table2].[Key2]
WHERE [NotActive] IS NOT NULL
```

(needed to alter the names from the data, so if there is an error it is because of the transcript)

I wanted to rewrite it so I have:

```sql
USE[database]

SELECT [table2].[NotActive]
       ,[table2].[Name]
       ,[tabel1].[Time]
       ,[table1].[Region]   
FROM (
      SELECT [RegionList].[Cluster]
         ,[RegionList].[Region]
         ,[Customer]
         ,[Key1]
         ,[Key2]
         ,MAX(..[TimeK].) AS [Time]
      FROM [table3]
      JOIN [RegionList] ON [RegionList].[Region] = [DRegion].[Region]
      JOIN [DTime] ON [table3].[TimeK] = [DTime].[TimeK]
      JOIN [PKey]  ON [table3].[Key2] = [PKey].[Key2]

      GROUP BY [RegionList].[Cluster]
         ,[RegionList].[Region]
         ,[Customer]
         ,[Key1]
         ,[Key2]
      ) AS [table1],
    (
      SELECT [table3].[Name]
        ,[DProduct].[Product]
        ,[PKey].[Key2]
        ,CASE
             WHEN [table1].[time] IS NULL THEN [DProduct].[Product]
             WHEN ...
             ELSE NULL
        END AS [NotActive]
      FROM [table1]
      JOIN [DProduct] ON [table1].[Key1] = [DProduct].[Key1]
      JOIN [PKey]  ON [table3].[Key2] = [PKey].[Key2]
      JOIN [Name] ON [table3].[Name] = [DName].[Name]
    ) AS [table2]

WHERE [NotActive] IS NOT NULL
```

But now in the second part of the statement there is the "multi-part identifier [table1] could not be bound" error. I know that at this part it doesn't "see" [table1] but what do I do? Is there an easy fix? Or am I on the wrong way?

Comment: Show us some sample table data and the expected result - all as formatted text, mnot images. (Take a look at [mcve] before you start.)

Comment: Why do you want to rewrite the query? Assuming the queries are equivalent they won't behave any different. A CTE is essentially used as a subquery - the CTE statement gets expaned in the query. Which means the second query isn't the equivalent of the first - `FROM [table1]` should be `FROM (.... table1 query ...)`

Comment: The second query doesn't join the two subqueries. Another problem is that the `table2` CTE uses `table1` but so does the final query. Why are you trying to remove the CTEs in the first place? This won't fix any performance problems - it's the `GROUP BY` in the subqueries that causes the problems

Comment: I want to rewrite the query because I got a hint that the "With" statement could be the problem, so I want to try a drifferent approch to check if it is the "WITH" statement or if there is an other problem.

Comment: I am sorry I haven't shortend the code more down but I think then the main problem perhabs won't be clear.

Comment: It's not a `;WITH` statement, it's just `WITH`. `;` is a statement terminator, it should go at the end of **all** your statements; it's not a "beginningator" for `WITH` and `MERGE` statements.

Comment: the second query is my first idea of what I could do else, you mean if I get the Join correct the "could not be bound" error would disapper?

Comment: You "got a hint" that the `WITH` statement could be the problem.  Where was this "hint" from, was it from the execution plan, or was it from your own head, i.e. just a hunch?  When your query is compiled it will run pretty much the same way regardless if you use `WITH` or correlated subqueries, unless you are fundamentally changing the actual logic.  From your description, it sounds much more likely that you have some sort of contention/ locking issue.

Comment: I got that hint from a specialist who is working with the tables on an other company, I just hoped to find a way to rewirte the "WITH" statement so that I don't have to use it and to find out if there are other problems as well or if it is just the "WITH" statement. The second query is just  one of my ideas, that didn't worked out.

Comment: Rewriting a `WITH` into subqueries does nothing; that's what the optimizer already does. The reason CTEs can be "the problem" is that the engine does not materialize intermediate results -- the whole thing will be treated as one giant query and optimized as such. Depending on what your query does, you can get better results by inserting data into a temporary table first (`SELECT ... INTO #table  ...`)  instead of a CTE, as the optimizer can then make use of full statistics on this data, instead of the estimates it has to use for subqueries.